# jQuery .click() method not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function that, on clicking a certain element, would replace a div with a hidden span. When I had the event handler in the "onclick=" attr in the tag, the function worked fine. But then I tried to get "fancy" and replace onclick attr with jQuery's .click() method. Now, when I try to use it on the page, nothing but a *clunk* -- nothing happens.

However, if I execute the **exact same code** in Chrome's js console, it works great. Here is my js:

```
$("a#delete").click(function () {
    $("a#delete").replaceWith($("span.hconf").attr("style", "none"))
});
```

Here is the relevant html (the  is inside a div, the  is outside):

```
<a class='modify' id="delete" u="{{ i.id }}" href='#'>delete</a>
<span class='hconf' style="display:none;">Are you sure? <a class='confirm' id='del_conf_true' onclick='deltrue();' href='#'>yes</a> | <a class='confirm' id='del_conf_false' href='#'>no</a></span>
```

I know I can change the second $("a#delete") with the "this" keyword, but I am leaving that undone now as I'm not sure if that's part of the problem. I am a newcomer to js/jQuery.

Comment: Is "delete" an identifier or a CSS class?

Comment: "delete" is an identifier. I'm new to HTML and CSS too, so I'm sure I'm doing it wrong on that end. I am just concerned about the js logic atm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#delete").click(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith($("span.hconf").attr("style", "display:none"));
    });
});
```

...and don't you mean style="display:none"? You can just as easily use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$("span.hconf").hide();
```

And lastly, it is pointless using a filtering tag on an ID selector. Just do `$("#delete")`, it is both shorter and quicker.

Comment: Thank you as well for the updates re: .hide() and my code redundancy with filters.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running **before** the "delete" anchor HTML is seen by the browser. Thus your jQuery selector "a#delete" finds nothing, and so overall nothing happens. By putting your initialization code in a "ready" handler:

```
$(function() {
  $('a#delete').click(function() { /* ... */ });
});
```

you defer its execution to a point at which the whole document has been parsed. Alternatively, you could put your script block at the end of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

This JS is being ran before the DOM is ready, try putting this code inside a `$(function(){})` (DOM ready) block.

```
$(function(){
  $("a#delete").click(function () {
    $("a#delete").replaceWith($("span.hconf").attr("style", "display:none"));
  });
});
```

Or, you can try to use `.live`.

```
  $("a#delete").live('click', function () {
    $("a#delete").replaceWith($("span.hconf").attr("style", "display:none"));
  });
```

NOTE: Use `.hide()` and `.show()` to change the display attribute.